# filter in swift

Tags: массивы, ios, swift, filter, index

```
@IBAction func itemsHidden(button: UIButton) {
button.hidden = true
if let index = item.indexOf(button) {
item.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Как в данном случае можно воспользоваться `filter` в отношении `index`, который был удален из массива?

я пробовал:

`let filterIndex = item.filter { $0 == index}`

но это не работает.

Comment: можно задачу объяснить. что именно вы хотите получить

Comment: Я хочу через filter отобрать те элементы, которые были удалены через removeAtIndex.

Comment: то есть вы хотите найти в массиве те элементы, которых в нем уже нет? оригинально :)

Comment: :/ согласен) как можно тогда отобрать такие элементы?

Comment: создайте дополнительный массив и когда удаляете элементы из первого, перекладывайте их во второй. либо (насколько я понимаю массив состоит из UIButton), не удаляйте, а фильтруйте по hidden

Comment: фильтр для hidden будет выглядеть вот так `let newArray = item.filter({$0.hidden == false})`

Comment: ок. попробую. тоже уже подумал, что надо убирать removeAtIndex. спасибо